# Is it possible to re-use a Kohana ORM query for the row count?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

So I have my query as so...

```
$records = ORM::factory('category');
```

Add a WHERE clause as so...

```
$records = $records->where('categoryid', 'LIKE', 'aa');
```

Grab a count for pagination as so...

```
$count = $records->count_all();
```

And my where clause gets cleared away as so...

```
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

With this line commented out

```
//$count = $records->count_all();
```

My SQL looks just fine...

```
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categoryid` LIKE 'aa' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Is it possible to use a single query the way I'm trying to or do I have to make two duplicate identical queries? One for the count, and one for the actual results...

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use special `reset(FALSE)` call:

```
$records = $records->where('categoryid', 'LIKE', 'aa');
$records->reset(FALSE); // !!!!
$count = $records->count_all();
$categories = $records->find_all();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a very brief and clear answer. Not to impose but you wouldn't happen to know by chance how to do that with just the database module? Particularly this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617760/when-using-kohana-db-how-does-one-avoid-duplicate-code-when-needing-a-count-for  Wellp anyways... thank you again...