# When using Kohana DB, how does one avoid duplicate code when needing a count for pagination?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-db

Using the Kohana query builder, is it possible to build my query piece by piece.

Then execute a count on said query.

Then execute the query itself.

All without having to write duplicate conditionals... one for the count and one for the results...

Adding

```
DB::select(array('COUNT("pid")', 'mycount'))
```

To the main query results in only getting back one record.

Is it maybe possible to execute the count, and somehow remove

```
array('COUNT("pid")', 'mycount')
```

from the select...

Right now the only way I can think of is a find and replace on the SQL code itself, and then just running said code SQL... there must be a better way though... I hope...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do just that I use 3 methods. First one returns the paginated results, second one gets the count. Third, private method, holds common conditions used by #1 and #2. If the query needs to use JOINs or WHEREs or anything like that, it all goes to #3. This way there is no need to repeat the query.

```
/* 1 */
public function get_stuff($pagination = false){
    $query = DB::select(/* ... columns here ... */);
    $query = $this->get_stuff_query($query);
    if($pagination) $query->limit($pagination->items_per_page)->offset($pagination->offset);
    return $query->execute();
}

/* 2 */
public function get_stuff_count(){
    $query = DB::select(array('COUNT("id")', 'total_rows'));
    $query = $this->get_stuff_query($query);
    $result = $query->execute();
    return $result->get('total_rows',0);
}

/* 3 */
private function get_stuff_query($query){
    $query->from(/* tablename */);
    $query->join(/* ... */);
    $query->where(/* ... */);
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [count_last_query()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Database#count_last_query)

```
// $db is a Database instance object
$count = $db->count_last_query();
```

Comment: The reason I couldn't have used this is that I wanted to get the count first, then execute the query.